# jquery anything slider / jquery.pngfix ie6 problem

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

Seem to have a problem in ie6

Using anything slider, with the slider nav using png's but when I add the jquery pngfix the slider nav's don't appear to work anymore.

Anybody else experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it, well cheated a little..

For ie6 I used gif's and stripped png fix out.  doesn't quite look right but its only for ie6 users

Answer (score 0):

IE6 is now around 3% of the browser share and falling (down from 10% a year ago).  http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Why tear your hair out over it any longer?   Good riddance IE6.

If it is a problem, detect IE6 and redirect people to a "time to upgrade" page.

Comment: I agree, normall I check that sites are usable within ie6, but in this case the client has noticed this and unfortunately it's left me with no hair! :-( So ideally I need to try and sort it out somehow.